# Module not found: Can't resolve 'React' using npm package

Tags: javascript, reactjs, webpack, next.js

I am using a simple package in `nextjs` project  getting this error
**Module not found: Can't resolve 'React'**
I am trying to use this package
https://www.npmjs.com/package/button-publishing

Git repo : https://github.com/naveennsit/button-ns

Plugin have only `hello world` example

I am using like this

```
import Test from 'button-publishing'


function HomePage() {
  return <Test/>
}

export default HomePage
```

here is my code
https://repl.it/@naveennsit/LastingKosherMonitor#pages/index.js

[image]

Comment: Have you tried running it locally instead of in the cloud?

Comment: yes facing same issue